# Getting the User ID from the last line of the /etc/passwd file in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, scripting, command

I've been trying the following:

```
cut -d: -f3 | last -1 /etc/passwd
```

and

```
last -1 | cut -d: -f3 /etc/passwd
```

These statements aren't working, I'm not sure how to join both of them to get the result I want. It just takes the current command that is in front of the /etc/passwd directory.

I'm fairly new to Linux and combining commands together.

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: try `tail -1 /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f3`. You have misunderstood the flow of information along a pipe.  It goes from the program of the left to the program of the right.  `last(1)` allows to get your last logins to the system, not the last lines of a file... the command is `tail(1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
cut -d: -f3 /etc/passwd | tail -1
```

Or:

```
tail -1 /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f3
```

#### Notes

1. The command `last` shows a listing of last logged in users.  By contrast, `tail` provides the end of a file and `tail -1` provides just the last line.
2. Consider this command:

   ```
   cut -d: -f3 | last -1 /etc/passwd
   ```

   This runs `cut -d: -f3` but since in file names are provided, `cut` will wait for you to provide input on stdin.  This is not what you want.  By contrast, the command below provides the file `/etc/passwd` as input to `cut` and then selects the last line of cut's output:

   ```
   cut -d: -f3 /etc/passwd | tail -1
   ```